# batch file : overwrite one file to several existing files

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make simple security program for my company. 
We usually make a lot of doc or ppt(x) files and 
for some reason, we need to make them disable as soon as possible.
So we usually deleted the all of files but It took so long.
So I thought I can do that by overwritting the files.
If I have a empty doc or ppt files then overwite all of doc, ppt files in working drive each, then it will be faster and much safer than just deleting.
So I tried to use xcopy
Assuming empty.doc is just empty doc file and

```
xcopy /s /y c:\users\mycom\empty.doc c:\*.doc
```

But it said cannot perform cyclic copy
I need you guys help
and I am glad to hear suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Put the empty.doc on a different drive.  CDROM or USB or HDD etc.

Comment: Why should overwriting be faster and safer than deleting?

Comment: @aschipfl in my opinion, overwriting with less than 1kb files to original files can be faster than deleting over 1kb files plus if I delete the files ppl can recover that files by some program or by data recovery company. But if I overwrite the original files, then they cannot guess what it was unless they got bak files

Comment: Why should overwriting be faster than deleting? anyway, deleting removes the entry in the folile allocation table but leaves the data in the sectors of the HDD (they are just marked as free); overwriting with small file will just overwrite first sector but leaves the remaining ones, so they could also be restored; to safely delete files you need to swipe (delete entry in file allocation table and overwrite all sectors with dummy or random data, even multiple times)...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old, old batch file that I employed for such an endeavour:

```
:: dispose.bat
@echo off
:: Check parameter(s), stripping quotes
set yp1=%1
set ydf=
:insistp1 
if defined yp1 set yp1=%yp1:"=%
if not defined yp1 for %%i in (echo goto) do %%i error - filename required
if not exist "%yp1%" for %%i in (echo goto) do %%i error - file not found
for %%i in ("%yp1%") do (set yfr=%%i&call :zapit %%~di)  2>nul

:error
:: Clean up variables used
if defined ydf echo Warning! dispose failed!!
for %%i in (yp1 yfr yrn ydf) do set %%i=
goto :eof

:zapit
set yfr=%yfr:"=%
IF /i %1 == u: DEL "%yfr%" &goto :eof
if not exist %1\delete\. md %1\delete
(set yrn=)
:rndloop
set yrn=%yrn%%random%
if exist %1\delete\%yrn% goto rndloop
if not exist "%yfr%" set ydf=Y&goto :eof
move "%yfr%" %1\delete\%yrn%>nul
goto :eof


:: dispose.bat ends
```

Noting that `u:` is a RAMDRIVE on my system, hence mere deletion is all that is required.

The purpose is not to actually *delete* the files, but to move them to a directory named `?:\delete` and provide them with a random name in that directory.

Since the file is simply `MOVE`d it is quite fast, which addresses your time consideration.

An issue for me is the idea of `copy`ing a file over all of the files you target. If the file that you copy is shorter than the other files, some data wilstill be available to be recovered. Regardless, it will alwats be slower than simply deleting the files (which you say you are currently doing.)

This scheme simply accumulates the files-to-be-deleted in a known directory on the same drive (so they will simply be `move`d, not `copied`.)

Once they are in your `\delete` directory, you can let a utility like `ccleaner` or `recuva` loose on that single directory in the background and it will overwrite the files a specified number of times.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help btw is there any way I just overwrite one file to several files?

Comment: `for /r "d:\starting directory" %%x in (*.doc? *.ppt?) do copy /y "thefilenameyouwanttocopyoverthefiles" %%a >nul` Use with caution - will silently overwrite the first part of all files matching the masks provided, leaving the remainder recoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler method.  Be careful.

At the command line:

```
for /r c:\ %A in (*.doc? *.ppt?) do echo. > %A
```

In a batch file:

```
for /r c:\ %%A in (*.doc? *.ppt?) do echo. > %%A
```

**EDIT:**

To replace with a file, see the example below.  Replace the example's `d:\path\file.ext` with your intended file.  Note that the previous option will work much faster with a similar result.

At the command line:

```
for /r c:\ %A in (*.doc? *.ppt?) do copy d:\path\file.ext > %A
```

In a batch file:

```
for /r c:\ %%A in (*.doc? *.ppt?) do copy d:\path\file.ext > %%A
```

Either way, as noted in Magoo's answer, larger files will still have recoverable data on the drive.  You stated in a comment:

> But if I overwrite the original files, then they cannot guess what it
>   was unless they got bak files

This isn't accurate. Forensic tools can retrieve the partial data that wasn't overwritten with new content.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help btw is there any way I just overwrite one file to several files? your code is perfect but for some reason, I wonder how to overwrite

Comment: Overwrite is automatic. If you want to use a file instead, please see my revised answer.